# Filter the types of a parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I'd like to know if it's possible to filter the types passed to a variadic template (based on a predicate template) to produce another variadic template containing those types which satisfy the predicate:

```
/** Filter a parameter pack */    
template <template <class> class,
          template <class...> class,
          class...>
struct filter;
template <template <class> class Pred, template <class...> class Variadic>
struct filter<Pred, Variadic> : Variadic<>
{};
template <template <class> class Pred,
          template <class...> class Variadic,
          class T, class... Ts>
struct filter<Pred, Variadic, T, Ts...>
{
    // FIXME: this just stops at first T where Pred<T> is true
    using type = typename std::conditional<
        Pred<T>::value,
        Variadic<T, Ts...>,    // can't do: Variadic<T, filter<...>>
        filter<Pred, Variadic, Ts...> >::type;
};
```

As you can see, I haven't found a way to "extract" the parameter pack from the rest of the filtered types.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That should be fairly straight-forward. At the heart you should have something like this:

```
template <typename...> struct filter;

template <> struct filter<> { using type = std::tuple<>; };

template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>
struct filter<Head, Tail...>
{
    using type = typename std::conditional<Predicate<Head>::value,
                               typename Cons<Head, typename filter<Tail...>::type>::type,
                               typename filter<Tail...>::type
                          >::type;
};
```

You just need `Cons<T, Tuple>`, which turns `T, std::tuple<Args...>` into `std::tuple<T, Args...>`, and you need to pass the predicate along (left as an exercise). `Cons` could look like this:

```
template <typename, typename> struct Cons;

template <typename  T, typename ...Args>
struct Cons<T, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T, Args...>;
};
```

The result of `filter<Args...>::type` would be `std::tuple<Brgs...>`, where `Brgs...` is a pack consisting of only those types in `Args...` for which the predicate holds.

Comment: There's something I'm still not understanding, but the compiler errors aren't helping. I have posted here http://ideone.com/USTnJR, if you wouldn't mind taking another look - it doesn't seem proper to edit the original.

Comment: That version had another problem, use this one: http://ideone.com/eh3Epd. As you can see, the ::type members of filter and Cons are not recognized as types.

Comment: @roysc: `Cons` should be specialized for tuples. Let me edit this. [Edit:] Done. I've also amended the main template to have a proper base case.

Comment: Awesome! That's basically what I had - turns out I needed more `typename`s to help the compiler.

Comment: @scry: [Fixed version](https://ideone.com/MzUtL6) with additional `typename`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Does this post need further edits? Could you perhaps make or propose one?

Comment: You provide guidance and exercise that OP mostly succeed to turn in working code (with missing `typename`) in comment. User from another question copy/paste your guidance code and complain about issue (as missing `Predicate`). So providing final result (as provided in comment) would be fine IMO.