# Filter types in a parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, c++20, parameter-pack

Im trying create a filtered type of a variadic template/parameter pack and also preserve ordering.

```cpp
// example what im trying to accomplish
template<typename... Args>
struct query
{
    using filtered = typename filtered<std::is_integral_v, Args...>
}
```

In this example filtered would filter all integral types eg.

```
query<int, A, B>::filtered == query<A, B>::filtered
```

How can I create a util like this or something that would achieve the same results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter the types of a parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366398/filter-the-types-of-a-parameter-pack)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't compile for me (where does he define Predicate?), haven't found a solution that does what I want.

Comment: That answer gave hints, not full code, but comment has the full code [Demo](https://ideone.com/MzUtL6).

Comment: ah I see my bad. Thanks that code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment by @Jarod42 has demo with working code

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<template<class> class, template<class...> class, class...>
struct filter;
template<template<class> class Pred, template<class...> class Variadic>
struct filter<Pred, Variadic>
{
    using type = Variadic<>;
};

template<template<class> class Pred,
         template<class...> class Variadic,
         class T,
         class... Ts>
struct filter<Pred, Variadic, T, Ts...>
{
    template<class, class>
    struct Cons;
    template<class Head, class... Tail>
    struct Cons<Head, Variadic<Tail...>>
    {
        using type = Variadic<Head, Tail...>;
    };

    using type = typename std::conditional<
      Pred<T>::value,
      typename Cons<T, typename filter<Pred, Variadic, Ts...>::type>::type,
      typename filter<Pred, Variadic, Ts...>::type>::type;
};
```

And integration with my example

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
struct query
{
    using filtered = filter<std::is_integral, std::tuple, Args...>::type
}
```

Comment: I suggest to copy-paste the full code into the answer itself (with attribution). If the link dies, the answer will become useless otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_filterp_l), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```
using filtered = mp_filter<std::is_integral, mp_list<Args...>>;
```

Note that if you want this to be a `std::tuple`, that's:

```
using filtered = mp_filter<std::is_integral, std::tuple<Args...>>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid recursion using `std::tuple_cat()`

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <template <typename> class F, typename T>
std::enable_if_t<true == F<T>::value, std::tuple<>> filter ();

template <template <typename> class F, typename T>
std::enable_if_t<false == F<T>::value, std::tuple<T>> filter ();

template <typename...>
struct query;

template <typename ... Ts>
query<Ts...> deTuple (std::tuple<Ts...>);

template <template <typename> class F, typename ... Ts>
struct filtered
 { using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(filter<F, Ts>()...)); };

template<typename... Args>
struct query
{
    using filtered = decltype(deTuple(std::declval<
      typename filtered<std::is_integral, Args...>::type>()));
};

class A {};
class B {};

int main ()
 {
   using T1 = typename query<int, A, B>::filtered;
   using T2 = query<A, B>;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T1, T2> );
 }
```